# Select anywhere inside Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to create a screen, or border where if the user click anywhere inside within this border. It should turn my border color RED. Currently i have my XAML setup as...

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" Width="200" Height="200">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click anywhere in here, the border should turn red" />
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" Width="200" Height="200">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click anywhere in here, the border should turn red" />
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" Width="200" Height="200">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click anywhere in here, the border should turn red" />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

And the output looks like this...

[image]

The problem now is that the "Border" is unable to recognize my MouseDown button. It doesnt register my mousedown anywhere inside the border, but only on the border itself. I want it so that if the user click anywhere inside, it should change my border color. How can i do that?

Please note that i need to eventually put content inside my border, be it a video, images, multiple UI controls, or whatever, so if user click anything inside this border, it should "select" my border and turn it red.

I experimented with other things like a Rectangle but Rectangle i cannot use because i am unable to put other UI elements or control in there.

Anyone know what is the correct way to do it?

Requirement:

- within border selection, turn border red.
- within border unselection, turn border back to blue.
- border should eventually allow contents inside, such as the textblock, images, video, or anything.

Comment: I would recommend to use ListBox, whcih supports selection out-of-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a transparent background to capture mouse clicks

```
<Border Background="Transparent" Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="OnMouseDown" Width="200" Height="200">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click anywhere in here, the border should turn red" />
</Border>
```

Note that any controls inside the border could steal events away from the border. In that case you may need a transparent border over the top of everything, or handle routed events. or just use a ToggleButton instead and change its template.

Comment: Or use `PreviewMouseDown` instead of `MouseDown` to check for mouse click before any control inside the border receives the click. If you use `PreviewMouseDown` you can set `e.Handled` to `true` or `false` depending whether you want to "eat" the click or not (respectively).

Comment: This is the best answser so far, will accept this. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel MouseDown="OnMouseDown">
            <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"  Width="200" Height="200">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Click anywhere in here, the border should turn red" />
            </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Wrap it inside container..